# Why Java couldn't figure out some obvious illegal casts when type parameters are involved?

Tags: java, generics, casting, jls

Consider the following example:

```
public class Example {
    public static <T> void f(T obj) {
        Integer i = (Integer) obj; // runtime error
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f("hello");
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why Java cannot figure out that cast in line 3 is illegal in compile time? Surely, because of the type erasure, the signature of the function in runtime will be `f(Object obj)`, but it seems to me that in the compile-time it's enough information to catch the error.

Compare this with the case:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add(42); // compile-time error
ls.add("foo");
Integer i = ls.get(0); // compile-time error
```

where a type parameter is involved but the error succesfully detected in the compile-time.

If the answer is "the compiler is just not smart enough", then is there any reason (for backward compatibility?) why it can't be made smarter?

Comment: In the first case you are using a _cast_, which literally has the semantics of "Trust me, compiler! I assure you this will work!". The compiler sees that there _are_ cases where this will work, and trusts you.

Comment: In fact, the JLS does not allow all casts though. It wont compile if the cast can be proven to be impossible. For example if you have two local variables, one a `Car` and you are trying to cast it to a `Dog`. @Sweeper

Comment: @Zabuzard Yes, that's why I included the phrase "The compiler sees that there are cases where this will work".

Comment: Note that `<T> void f(T obj)` is in effect very close to `void f(Object obj)` (which happens to be its erasure) and here it's much clearer why it's accepted: an object referenced by an `Object` variable *could* be an `Integer`, therefore the cast is allowed. If it isn't then you'll get a Runtime error. And if you then look separately at a callsite: an `Object` parameter can obviously accept a `String` parameter (since it's a subtype of `Object`).

Comment: @Zabuzard in this case, `List<E>` should also accept anything because `E` is treated as `Object` in runtime (if not bounded), but it doesn't happen because the compiler is able to figure out that `add()` is called with the wrong type of an argument. So the confusing part is sometimes (I assume in the most obvious cases) the compiler can figure out type violations when in other it simply warns you with the "unchecked" warning.

Comment: That is something different. Generics provide compile-time safety if you do not intentionally bypass it with casts. `list.add("hello")` is different to `list.add((E) "hello")`. And both of them are different again to what you have here, namely `(Integer) list.get(0)`.

Comment: @avli: the difference is that the `List<E>` is restrictive. If you define a `List<String>` then the compiler knows that `<E>` is meant to mean `<String>` in this case. But your method definition has an unbounded type `<T>` which just means "accepts whatever", which is really kind-of pointless in your example (since it behaves exactly the same as not having a type parameter at all and accepting `Object`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I agree that the method parameter is pointless in my example. It's added to illustrate the case where though the compiler has all the type information in the compile-time (`obj` is a `String`), it doesn't prevent the cast from `String` to `Integer`, which will definitely fail. So calling `f()` with a `String` parameter should be illegal on the first place. The whole thing illustrates that the compiler somewhat limits its reasoning and does not take into account the method body even though some bad casts are obvious.

Comment: @avli: the only reason the bad casts are possible is because you create a pointless type signature. The method definition is the boundary where it stops looking (and that's quite common among all languages). If you do something pointless within the method definition then you're allowed to shoot yourself in the foot. I don't understand why you're trying to rephrase this as "the compiler should know, it's obvious".

Comment: Let me explain, `String s = "foo"; Integer i = (Integer) s` - the compiler won't allow this, because it knows the types are incompatible. In my example, in the compile-time the compiler has the information about what T is actually is, and it's not compatible with the cast. My question was is there any reason why it couldn't throw a compile-time error in such cases. The answer seems to be it could, but would require a lot of static analysis in many cases. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @avli I added an appendix to my answer which hopefully addresses your follow up questions :)

Comment: @avli Don't forget that if `Example` were part of a library, it might be used by _other people's_ code. How is _your compiler_ going to analyse other people's code to check if they are calling `f` with `T == Integer`, in order to determine whether the cast is valid?

Comment: @Sweeper not sure I understand your point about the library. Do you mean the source of `f` won't be available?

Comment: @JoachimSauer your remark about "the method definition is the boundary where it stops looking" is indeed insightful. It's actually a huge part of the answer for the question in a sense it enables one to reason about what to expect from the generic facility. Thank you! I'm wondering if it's mentioned in JLS somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

Java, based on its current rule set (see the JLS) has to treat the **method content** and its **call-site** **separately**.

---

### Method content

The cast

```
(Integer) obj
```

has to be allowed at compile-time since `T` could be an `Integer`. After all, a call like

```
f(4)
```

should succeed and be allowed.

Java is not allowed to take in the call-site of the method into consideration. Also, this would imply that Java would have to scan **all call-sites** but this is impossible since that would also include possible *future call-sites* that have not been written yet or are included later on, in case you are writing a library.

---

### Call-site

The call-site also has to be legal since Java is not allowed to take the method-content into consideration.

The signature demands `T` (`extends Object`) and `String` fullfills that. So it is allowed to be called like that.

If Java *would* also check the content, imagine you would hide the cast 3 levels depper in some other method calls. Then Java not only has to check `f`s code but also the code of those methods and possibly all their `if` statements to check if the line with the bad cast is even reached.
It is NP-hard to prove that with 100% certanity at compile-time, hence it is also not part of the rule set.

---

### Why?

While we saw that such situations are not always easy to detect and that actually proving it for all possible situations might even be *impossible* (NP-hard), Java designers could certainly have added some weaker rules that cover the dangerous situations partially.

Also, there are actually some similar situations in which Java will help you out with weaker rules. For example a cast like

```
House a = new House();
Dog b = (Dog) a;
```

is forbidden because Java can prove easily that the types are completely unrelated. But as soon as the setup becomes more complex, with types coming from other methods, generics, Java can not easily check it anymore.

All in all, you will have to ask a Java Language Designer for the precise reasons in the decision making. It is what it is.

---

### Static code analysis

What you have here is typically the job of a static code analyzer (like most IDEs already include). They will actually scan through your code, all usages and so on and try to figure out if your current code flow has possible issues.

It is important to note that this also includes a lot of false-positives, as we just learned that not all of such usages might actually be wrong, some dangerous setups might be intended.

---

### Appendix: Comments

Based on the discussion in the comments, let me stress out the fact that your particular example is indeed **simple to prove to be wrong**. So the call-site **could easily be forbidden** in this particular case (any static code analyzer will happilly throw a warning at you for this code).

However, we can do very simple modifications to the code already that demonstrates why it is so difficult to actually prove errors when connecting the call-site with the content of the method.

So the tldr is that almost all real code situations require much more efforts for a tool to prove with 100% that the call is incorrect. Also, it is much more difficult to program this and it can not always be ensured that there are no false-positives. Which is why such stuff is typically not done by a compiler but rather by static code analyzers.

The two common examples for this are method nesting and code branching.

#### Nesting

Imagine you hide the cast `(Integer) obj` a level depper, in another method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    f("hello");
}

public static <T> void f(T obj) {
    g(obj);
}

public static <T> void g(T obj) {
    Integer i = (Integer) obj;
}
```

In order to prove this, Java would now have to connect the call-site from `main` to the content in `f`, to the call-site in `g`. If you add more levels of nesting this quickly gets out of control and needs a recursive deep analysis before anything can be proven.

#### Branching

Another very common but difficult situation for the compiler is if you hide the bad cast in a branched code flow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    f("hello");
}

public static <T> void f(T obj) {
    if (isMonday()) {
        Integer a = (Integer) obj;
    } else {
        String b = (String) obj;
    }
}
```

Now, Java would need knowledge about what `isMonday()` returns at compile-time, which is simply impossible.

But if Java flags this, it would be bad. Because, what if we ensure externally that we only launch the program mondays? It should work then.

Comment: That's a good point about the call-site. Maybe, I wasn't clear enough in the question. It's obvious for me why the parametrized method can accept anything that extends `Object`. And in my example, it's `f("hello")` call that should be illegal. I'm not sure though I understand you point about the future calls. Isn't it enough to check only the call sites that exist in the time of compilation?

Comment: @avli: a compiler *could* do that, but the rules of the Java language simply aren't set up this way.

Comment: `f("hello")` has to be legal since the method content can not be taken into consideration, it might be easy to prove in your case but there are much more complex cases when it can not be proven anymore (I added some paragraph to the answer), this is NP-hard. And the designers did not want to include rules that only sometimes work and sometimes dont. However, they could certainly have added stuff like _"only scan one level deep, ..."_, but they did not. Fun fact, similar situations do exist, e.g. recursion detection on static initialization, where Java will detect some issues, but not all.